# cout.setf(ios::fixed|ios::showpoint); Set precision exceed original number

Tags: c++

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    float f = 17793.03;
    cout.setf(ios::fixed|ios::showpoint);
    cout<<setprecision(3);
    cout<<f<<endl;
}
```

result
17793.029

I used to use Python and I do not know why this happened.
Thanks

Comment: Probably because the number `17793.03` cannot be encoded, so the compiler rounds it to the closest encodable float. Try a double.

Comment: It works fine now.Thanks but why double works?

Comment: float are encoded on 32 bits, double on 64 bits. So they have a "double" precision, so are more precise.

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the number 17793.03 cannot be encoded, so the compiler rounds it to the closest encodable float. Try a double

[EDIT] float are encoded on 32 bits, double on 64 bits. So they have a "double" precision, so are more precise

Answer (score 0):

In C++ floating-point literal is of type double by default.
If you do something like this:

```
float f = 17793.03; // implicit type conversions happen, 17793.03 is a double
```

You’re assigning a double to a float, which may or may not result in a loss of precision, compiler show a warning.
If you want a floating-point literal of type float, you must use the suffix f or F.
Compiler can’t just copy the bits representing the value 17793.03 into float f. Instead, it needs to convert the double 17793.03 to a floating point number.

You probably want this:

```
float f {17793.03F}; //float values typically have 7 digits of precision
cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(2) << f << std::endl; 
// Result: 17793.03
```

If you need more precision, use doubles:

```
double d {17793.03}; // typically have 16 digits of precision   
cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << d << endl;
// Result: 17793.030
```

Now here's a funny thing: Under the hood, Python float types are doubles.